# Why the howsmyssl.com TLS check is different from the cURL STDERR output in PHP

Tags: php, ssl, curl

For customer support purposes I want to check, which TLS version is used on an API request.
I made a php script using cURL to send a request to https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check and the answer was "TLS 1.3". I logged the same request with VERBOSE=true and find in this output "TLSv1.2" was used.

How that can be?

cURL Response:

```
{"given_cipher_suites":["TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384","TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256","TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256","TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384","TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384","TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384","TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256","TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256","TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256","TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256","TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256","TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256","TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384","TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384","TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256","TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256","TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256","TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256","TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA","TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA","TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA","TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA","TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA","TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA","TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384","TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256","TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256","TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256","TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA","TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA","TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV"],"ephemeral_keys_supported":true,"session_ticket_supported":false,"tls_compression_supported":false,"unknown_cipher_suite_supported":false,"beast_vuln":false,"able_to_detect_n_minus_one_splitting":false,"insecure_cipher_suites":{},"tls_version":"TLS 1.3","rating":"Probably Okay"}
```

STDERR output:

```
*   Trying 34.71.45.200:443...
* Connected to www.howsmyssl.com (34.71.45.200) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=www.howsmyssl.com
*  start date: Oct 30 02:45:45 2022 GMT
*  expire date: Jan 28 02:45:44 2023 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "www.howsmyssl.com" matched cert's "www.howsmyssl.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=R3
*  SSL certificate verify result: unable to get local issuer certificate (20), continuing anyway.
> GET /a/check HTTP/1.1
Host: www.howsmyssl.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en; rv:1.9.0.13) Gecko/2009073022 Firefox/3.5.2
Accept: */*

* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Length: 1459
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Connection: close
< Content-Type: application/json
< Date: Wed, 09 Nov 2022 08:08:44 GMT
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=631138519; includeSubdomains; preload
< 
* Closing connection 0
```

my PHP code: (I used [Kint](https://kint-php.github.io/kint/) to dump the variables)

```php
    $out = fopen('php://temp', 'w+');
    $curl = curl_init('https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check');

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en; rv:1.9.0.13) Gecko/2009073022 Firefox/3.5.2',
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_VERBOSE        => true,
        CURLOPT_STDERR         => $out,
        //CURLOPT_SSLVERSION => CURL_SSLVERSION_MAX_TLSv1_2, //6 = 1.2 | 4 = 1.1.1m
    ));
    $curl_result = curl_exec($curl);
    if ($curl_result)
    {
        Kint::dump($curl_result);
    }
    
    rewind($out);
    curl_close($curl);
    $TLS_logOutput = stream_get_contents($out);
    Kint::dump($TLS_logOutput);
```

Answer (score 1):

howsmyssl.com shows only the capabilities of the client but does not actually use the best of the capabilities. It will show which ciphers and protocol version (and other information) are supported by the client based on the ClientHello handshake packet. But it will currently only use TLS 1.2 (or lower, depending on what the client can) for the TLS connection with the client, even if the client could do better.

Thus, howsmyssl.com can used to find out what ciphers and protocol version a specific TLS client supports. Which of these is actually used against a specific server (like in case of your API client against the API server) depends on what the server supports though - and in case of howsmyssl.com the server currently does not support TLS 1.3.

Comment: Thx Steffen, but this confuses me even more now. I thought howsmyssl.com shows MY SSL version. As the name promises. TLS1.3 is not active on my PC. If I set CURLOPT_SSLVERSION to TLS1_3, the result is the same. If I set the option to TLS1_2, both outputs are also TLS1.2

Comment: @mikexmagic: I confused this initially with a different service. I reworked my question to show what is actually happening.